# Getting the drive letter of a volumename in Windows command-line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, volume

For a backup script running under the command-line interface in Windows I want to get the drive letter of a certain hard disk volume (stored in the variable `%lookfor%`). This is the code I have come up with so far.

```
set lookfor=yourvolume
for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%D in ('wmic logicaldisk get VolumeName^, Caption^') Do ( 
 if %%F equ "" (
        @echo %%D has the VolumeName %%E
        if "%%E" equ "%lookfor%" (
            set letter=%%D
        )
    ) else (
        @echo %%D has the VolumeName %%E %%F
        if "%%F" equ "%lookfor%" (
        set letter=%%D
        )
    )
 )
echo The Volume %lookfor% has the driveletter %letter%
```

The assignment of the driveletter to the variable driveletter obviously fails. How can I address this?

Answer (score 1):

Use WMIC's `where` parameter to specify what to look for:

```
for /f %%a in ('
    wmic logicaldisk where "VolumeName='%lookfor%'" get Caption ^| find ":"
') do set letter=%%a
```

Comment: Thx so much!! It works perfectly and is so much simpler and shorter than my code

Comment: @KarlMorrison you can google up the error message, here's what I found: ['wmic' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](//superuser.com/a/1178758)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us what `lookfor` is set to, nor what your `wmic` output is. Here's mine...

> Caption  VolumeName
>   C:
>   M:       XPC
>   N:
>   P:
>   Q:
>   R:       System Reserved
>   U:
>   V:
>   W:       System Reserved

Your line

```
if %%F equ "" (
```

is incorrect as `%%F` can never be identical to `""` You need

```
if "%%F" equ "" (
```

Hence, the `else` branch of the first `if` will *always* be taken.

Your

```
if "%%F" equ "%lookfor%" (
```

Intriguingly, correct syntax. We don't know what you're attempting to find, but using the example above, the settings should be:

```
%%D      |%%E       |%%F
Caption  |VolumeName|
C:       |          |
M:       |XPC       |
N:       |          |
P:       |          |
Q:       |          |
R:       |System    |Reserved
U:       |          |
V:       |          |
W:       |System    |Reserved
```

So `%%F` may not be what you expect.

Perhaps

```
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%D in (
  'wmic logicaldisk get VolumeName^, Caption^'
 ) Do (echo D=%%D E=%%E)
```

would be better for your purpose.

and

```
if /i ....
```

makes the comparison case-insensitive.

Comment: Thank you very much. The line `@echo %%D has the VolumeName %%E %%F` was actually only there to check whether the if condition had worked correctly and the control variables had beend assigned correctly. `%Lookfor%` must be adapted to whatever volumename you're looking for on your respective computer. The sense of the whole code snippet was to get the driveletter to a given volumename.